# Return background color of selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which cells in are colored meaningfully.

Does any body know how i can return the background color value of a current cell in Excel sheet?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `Cell.Interior.Color`, I've used it to count the number of cells in a range that have a given background color (ie. matching my legend).

Answer (score 25):

If you are looking at a Table, a Pivot Table, or something with conditional formatting, you can try:

```
ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

This also seems to work just fine on regular cells.

Comment: Finally this is a correct answer. The answers so far are wrong. Cell.Interior.Color always returns the same value, no matter what I have set it to (I tested with Office 2010 and some older versions). Excel has extremely wired behavior here.

Comment: I agree that this solution is the only one that works consistently to return, not set, the background color, as per the original question.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you can use this properties:

```
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex - one of 56 preset colors
```

and

```
ActiveCell.Interior.Color - RGB color, used like that:

ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,255)
```

Answer (score 8):

The code below gives the **HEX** and **RGB** value of the range whether **formatted using conditional formatting** or otherwise. If the range is not formatted using Conditional Formatting and you intend to use iColor function in the Excel as UDF. It won't work. Read the below excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel).

*Note that the **DisplayFormat** property does not work in user defined functions. For example, in a worksheet function that returns the interior color of a cell, if you use a line similar to:*

```
Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
```

*then the worksheet function executes to return a #VALUE! error.* If you are not finding color of the conditionally formatted range, then I encourage you to rather use

```
Range.Interior.ColorIndex
```

as then the function can also be used as UDF in Excel. Such as **iColor(B1,"HEX")**

```
Public Function iColor(rng As Range, Optional formatType As String) As Variant
'formatType: Hex for #RRGGBB, RGB for (R, G, B) and IDX for VBA Color Index
    Dim colorVal As Variant
    colorVal = rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Select Case UCase(formatType)
        Case "HEX"
            iColor = "#" & Format(Hex(colorVal Mod 256),"00") & _
                           Format(Hex((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256),"00") & _
                           Format(Hex((colorVal \ 65536)),"00")
        Case "RGB"
            iColor = Format((colorVal Mod 256),"00") & ", " & _
                     Format(((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256),"00") & ", " & _
                     Format((colorVal \ 65536),"00")
        Case "IDX"
            iColor = rng.Interior.ColorIndex
        Case Else
            iColor = colorVal
    End Select
End Function

'Example use of the iColor function
Sub Get_Color_Format()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Selection.Cells
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = iColor(rng, "HEX")
        rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = iColor(rng, "RGB")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I created a Module with your code, and in a cell typed "=icolor(A2, "HEX")", where A2 has a colored cell. I get an error in the Sub's For loop. I'm new to VBA. Can you please advise how to get this to work?

Comment: You get error while using user defined function iColor() or while running the sub-routine?

Comment: It's an error in the cell while using the function. It simply says "#VALUE!", even if I just enter "=icolor(A2)".

Comment: To avoid #Value!, please use rng.Interior.ColorIndex instead of rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color.

Comment: That got rid of the error - thanks! - but now the color is coming back the same for any cell. In a column of data that's been highlighted with Conditional Formatting, all cells give "-4142" as the value - whether or not they they met the condition to format as red.

Comment: To get the colour of conditional formatting, you have to use rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex which is not allowed in UDF. So, it's better to run the sub-routine instead of using UDF as given in the answer.

Comment: Thanks - that's great info I haven't seen anywhere else. I'm searching for how to run the sub by itself. Seems obvious but I keep running into walls.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue matching the cell color with the actual color of the presets despite using the same index from ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex.  Instead, I followed @jainashish [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519275/5625975) above and applied each RGB value into the VBA function.

```
Dim colorVal As Variant
colorVal = tempFile.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("F2").DisplayFormat.Interior.color

iColor = Format((colorVal Mod 256), "00") & ", " & _
    Format(((colorVal \ 256) Mod 256), "00") & ", " & _
    Format((colorVal \ 65536), "00")
iColorSplitRGB = Split(iColor, ",")
r = iColorSplitRGB(0)
g = iColorSplitRGB(1)
b = iColorSplitRGB(2)

tempFile.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B8").Interior.color = RGB(r, g, b)
```