# VBA Excel Lookup on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, xlookup, index-match

I have two workbooks where I need to do a lookup in between and obtain a value.
Workbook A with sheet "prices" needs to do a lookup for a specific price in Workbook B sheet "list" on multiple conditions in VBA Excel. I'm not sure how to solve it. With an Index/Match, a XLookup or maybe another solution.

[image: Workbook A sheet "prices"]

[image: Workbook B sheet "list"]

Workbook A sheet "prices" cell B5 needs to obtain the price from Workbook B sheet "list" cell D3 on the following conditions:
a. the name "4Fruits"
b. name of the fruit "Green Apple"
c. the price must be marked yellow.

Hope someone can solve this, thanks :)

Comment: As you mention VBA, do you have any attempt(s) with it to show us? Without VBA this won't be feasible, I believe. With VBA however, it becomes a lot easier since you can use variables to store the row and column from the Match function (for both of them) and then do a simple check of that cell's background color.

Comment: Please read the SO guidance on how to ask a question.

Comment: @Notus_Panda unfortunately I don't know how where to start to solve it with 3 conditions ...

Comment: Alright, here are a few links to help you further (we are not a site to provide full code, we're here to assist): using match in VBA (you can use it on a column (for the partner name) or a row (for the type of apple)): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match using variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables and background color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520570/return-background-color-of-selected-cell

Comment: If the cells are conditionally formatted, you could probably do it without vba since you could implement the logic of the condition into the formula retrieving the information.

Comment: @Notus_Panda the cells are not conditionally formatted, but I have something to start with. Thank you for your tips and links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with MATCH inside an UDF. My example is just in the same workbook but it will work on different workbooks.

[image]

Formula in cell B4 is:

`=GET_PRICE($D$1:$G$4,$A$1,A4)`

Code of this UDF:

```
Public Function GET_PRICE(ByVal RngPrices As Range, ByVal vPartner As String, vType As String) As Variant

Dim vRow As Long
Dim vColumn As Long

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    vRow = .Match(vPartner, RngPrices.Columns(1), 0)
    vColumn = .Match(vType, RngPrices.Rows(1), 0)
End With

'check color
If RngPrices.Cells(vRow, vColumn).Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
    GET_PRICE = RngPrices.Cells(vRow, vColumn).Value
Else
    'not yellow, return N/A
    GET_PRICE = "Nope"
End If

End Function
```

Notice this UDF will work only if the cells interior color is yellow (not Condittional formatting) and the partners name and products name are **exactly** the same.

Now, let's erase yello color of Green apple and see how the function will not bring the price because the cell it's not yellow.

[image]